# display input box in 1st row of each column

Tags: jquery, datatables

so i have this script from datatable where to display `input box` on each column..

```
var admin_table = $('#user_list').DataTable({

    ajax:{
        "url":"../functions/ajax/get_userlist.php",
        dataSrc:""
    },
    "columns": [
        {"data": "userfullname"},
        {"data": "address"},
        {"data": "barangay"},

    ]
});
```

but my problem is when i use this the the `input box` overlaps my table header what i wanted to achieve is to put the `input box` to the 1st row on each column..

```
$('#user_list thead th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

admin_table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
```

and here is my html code

```
<table id="user_list" class="table table-bordered" style="width: 100%">

   <thead>
           <tr>

               <th>User Fullname</th>
               <th>Address</th>
               <th>Barangay</th>

           </tr>
      </thead>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a draw callback to change the table every times it updates, you were trying to add the fields before the table was loaded:

```
var admin_table = $('#user_list').DataTable({

    ajax:{
        "url":"../functions/ajax/get_userlist.php",
        dataSrc:""
    },
    "columns": [
        {"data": "userfullname"},
        {"data": "address"},
        {"data": "barangay"},

    ],
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        $('#user_list tr:first td').each( function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
       });
    }
});
```

You can also use the [datatables events](http://m.datatables.net/reference/event/) to add the fields after the table draws.

Comment: show your html, you probably don't have a tbody element. Is your code inside the `$(document).ready(function() {})` ?

Comment: actually the data was being load by datatable plugin.. let me updte my question

Comment: if it isn't working, try creating a jsfiddle and post it here